Sum doesn't work as I expected
I'm trying to sum a bunch of polynomials. I'm implementing that:
Sum[Subscript[P, k][c] (k + x) z^(k + x), {k, -x, -1}]

and mathematica gives me back that

I wonder why it is giving me back this powers of Subscript[P,k]. I understood that it is kind of related to having x as a summation limit but didn't understand how and what I'm doing wrong.
My expectation was to receive
Subscript[P, -x+1][c] z^(1) + Subscript[P, -x+2][c] (2) z^(2) +
  ... + Subscript[P, -1][c](x-1) z^(x-1)

Do you have any guesses?

You are wondering why Mathematica is giving back this result, but the rest of us are wondering what you were expecting to get...

@bmf thanks for making it clear! I tried to refine the question.

It should give an unevaluated sum back as x is not know. Therefore I think this is an error and I would report it to: support@wolfrm.com.

It is a bug, but you can avoid it using P[k, c] instead of Subscript[P, k][c].

Do you think that creating a P[k]=Subscript[P,k][c] command would do the work or I'll be dealing with the same bug?

@azerbajdzan: Sum[P[k, c]  (k + x)  z^(k + x), {k, -x, -1}] returns the input.

@user64494 Exactly, what else should it return (when x is undefined)?

@azerbajdzan I added my expectation on the text. Your comment doesn't help.

@Felipe Your expectation is simply wrong, that is not how Sum works. But if you set, say, x=5 you get explicit output.

It's a bug...And yet another reason to avoid Subscript for variables. P[k] or P[k][c] etc. "work", although Sum cannot find a closed-form formula, which is not surprising, really.
